# How do i modify browser network call request body using TestCafe

Tags: javascript, automation, mocking, testcafe

I want to modify the API request body by interrupting the network calls using Testcafe.
I am aware I can modify the response body but I want to modify the request body instead, using testCafe's RequestMock().

Load the web app > Find the API using filter > Modify the request body > Pass the actual response to the web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [Custom Request Hook](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests#create-a-custom-request-hook) to modify the request body.

For example:

```
import { RequestHook } from "testcafe";

export class MyRequestHook extends RequestHook {
    onRequest (event) {
        if (event.requestOptions?.body)
            event.requestOptions.body = Buffer.from(event.requestOptions.body, "utf8");
    }
    onResponse (event) {}
}

const customHook = new MyRequestHook(/api/); 

fixture`Modify Request Body`
    .page`http://localhost:3001`
    .requestHooks(customHook);

test('Test', async t => {
    await t.click('button');
});
```